# How to change Rails dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Recently I got [the alert](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-65cv-r6x7-79hv) from Github

I wanted to update `actionview` as it was prescribed, but after running `bundle update actionview` I got:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionview":
In Gemfile:
actionview (>= 6.0.2.2)

rails (>= 6.0.2.1) was resolved to 6.0.2.1, which depends on
  actionview (= 6.0.2.1)
```

The problem is Rails doesn't (or don't (?)) use Gemfile to manage gems so I can't fix that lock. Please, help!

Comment: `actionview` comes with whole `rails` so you should do `bundle update rails`.

Comment: "The problem is Rails doesn't (or don't (?)) use Gemfile to manage gems" - this statement is completely false.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Comment: @max Well, I should have written - I haven't found a Gemfile inside railties.

Comment: Gems don't use their Gemfile to resolve dependencies. They use the [gemspec](https://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/). The gemspec for Railsties [is here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/railties.gemspec). Rails uses the Gemfile in your application to resolve its dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Gemfile also includes `rails` then `actionview` will be constrained by that, as indicated by the output of bundler (`actionview (= 6.0.2.1)`). This indicates that your current rails version will only accept version `6.0.2.1` of `actionview`.

`actionview` is one of the dependencies of `rails`. See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.2.2/rails.gemspec#L33

There you can also see that the versions are raised in lockstep. So in order to raise the version of `actionview` with rails in your Gemfile you can either run `bundle update rails` or look into the option of only including `actionview` in your Gemfile, but not `rails`. For the latter case you should then be able to re-run `bundle update actionview` to update `actionview`.

Comment: Fortunately, `bundle update rails` worked this time.